# Android TCP Client connection freezes iBeacon ranging

Tags: java, android, tcp, android-asynctask, ibeacon

I have an Android TCP client that communicates to the server through an Aysnctask so as not to freeze the UI. I am also ranging iBeacons and I am trying to send the iBeacon information to the server. However, when I press the connect button, the iBeacon ranging freezes, meaning the didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection iBeacons, Region region) method no longer works. Please let me know if you see anything that could potentially cause this issue. Is my asynctask accidently effecting the UI? Here is the relevant code:

On-Click for the connect button:

```
            case R.id.connect: 
            if(!connect.isChecked()) {
                //if(mTcpClient.isConnected) {
                    mTcpClient.sendMessage("close");
                    mTcpClient.stopClient();
                //}
            }
            if(connect.isChecked()) {
                new ConnectTask().execute("");
                sendMsg.setEnabled(true);
                msgBox.setEnabled(true);
                sendInfo.setEnabled(true);
                text.setText("Send a message...");
            }
            break;
```

Asynctask for server communication:

```
    //************************************************************************************
// ASYNCTASK: Creates connection to server
//************************************************************************************
public class ConnectTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,TcpClient> {
    @Override
    protected TcpClient doInBackground(String... message) {
        //we create a TCPClient object
        mTcpClient = new TcpClient(new TcpClient.OnMessageReceived() {
            @Override
            //here the messageReceived method is implemented
            public void messageReceived(String message) {
                //this method calls the onProgressUpdate

                publishProgress(message);
            }
        });
        ip = sharedPref.getString("ip_address", "");
        port = sharedPref.getString("port", "");
        mTcpClient.run(ip, port);
        return null;
    }

    //Provides Progress Updates (when message is received from server)
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        //here we can receive values when called from publishProgress
        //this function allows you to update the UI without hanging or any other problems
        //when you call your GUI object on it's .notifyDataSetChanged(), it will refresh automatically      
        text.setText("You got a message!!");
        text.setText("Message: ");
        toast = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Received Message: See Message Box", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
        try{ JSONObject jsonReceived = new JSONObject(values[0]);

            x = Integer.parseInt(jsonReceived.getString("x"));
            y = Integer.parseInt(jsonReceived.getString("y"));
            Log.i("TESTING", "x: " + x + "y: " + y);

        } catch (Exception je) {}

        message.setText(Arrays.toString(values));
        plotPoints(x, y);
    }

}
```

All of the Client Code:

```
public class TcpClient {

///SharedPreferences sharedPref; //For Settings to change Ip and Port
public static String SERVER_IP; //your computer IP address
public static int SERVER_PORT;
// message to send to the server
private String mServerMessage;
// sends message received notifications
private OnMessageReceived mMessageListener = null;
// while this is true, the server will continue running
private boolean mRun = false;
// used to send messages
private PrintWriter mBufferOut;
// used to read messages from the server
private BufferedReader mBufferIn;
public static boolean isConnected = false;
JSONObject jsonReceiver;


/**
 * Constructor of the class. OnMessagedReceived listens for the messages received from server
 */
public TcpClient(OnMessageReceived listener) {
    mMessageListener = listener;
}

/**
 * Sends the message entered by client to the server
 *
 * @param message text entered by client
 */
public void sendMessage(String message) {
    if (mBufferOut != null && !mBufferOut.checkError()) {
        mBufferOut.println(message);
        mBufferOut.flush();
    }
}

/**
 * Close the connection and release the members
 */
public void stopClient() {
    Log.i("Debug", "stopClient");

    // send mesage that we are closing the connection
    mRun = false;

    if (mBufferOut != null) {
        mBufferOut.flush();
        mBufferOut.close();
    }

    mMessageListener = null;
    mBufferIn = null;
    mBufferOut = null;
    mServerMessage = null;

    isConnected = false;

}


//Run takes two string arguments to specify IP Address and Port number.
public void run(String ipAddr, String port) {

    mRun = true;
    SERVER_IP = ipAddr;
    SERVER_PORT = Integer.parseInt(port);

    try {
        //here you must put your computer's IP address.
        InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);

        Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Connecting...");

        //create a socket to make the connection with the server
        Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVER_PORT);

        try {

            isConnected = true;
            //sends the message to the server
            mBufferOut = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);

            //receives the message which the server sends back
            mBufferIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            Log.i("TCP Client", "Created both Buffers");

            //in this while the client listens for the messages sent by the server
            while (mRun) {
                mServerMessage = mBufferIn.readLine();
                if (mServerMessage != null && mMessageListener != null) {
                    //call the method messageReceived from MyActivity class
                    mMessageListener.messageReceived(mServerMessage);
                }

            }
            Log.e("RESPONSE FROM SERVER", "S: Received Message: '" + mServerMessage + "'");

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("TCP", "S: Error", e);

        } finally {
            //the socket must be closed. It is not possible to reconnect to this socket
            // after it is closed, which means a new socket instance has to be created.
            socket.close();
        }


   } catch (Exception e) {

        Log.e("TCP", "C: Error", e);

    }

}

//Declare the interface. The method messageReceived(String message) will must be implemented in the MyActivity
//class at on asynckTask doInBackground
public interface OnMessageReceived {
    public void messageReceived(String message);
}
```

}

Please let me know if you have any suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: Does didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection iBeacons, Region region) still get called?  Add a debug line inside the method to find out.

Comment: Are you using TCP over mobile or wifi?  2.4 Ghz wifi and BLE have comparable frequencies and there's a known issue between the wifi & ble radios on the Nexus 4 for example.

Comment: Does your beacon code also use an AsyncTask?  In recent Android versions, all AsyncTasks run one after another on a single thread, so a lengthy one can block the others.  If you want the previous version parallel behavior you can specify that they should run on the thread pool when you execute them.